# Python3 -- 256 AES decryption and encryption + brute force is what I am attempting to acheive. Why am I running into an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7, python-3.4

*The Error Is:*

** Traceback (most recent call last): File "256AESKeyCracker.py", line 10, in  cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_EAX) AttributeError: module 'Crypto.Cipher.AES' has no attribute 'MODE_EAX' **

```
        import os, sys
        import subprocess
        import random
        from Crypto.Cipher import AES
        from random import choice
        # Brute Force AES Key Cracker File
        # Encryption:
        Data = open('Data.txt','r')
        key = b'WmZq4t7w!z%C*F-J@NcRfUjXn2r5u8x/'
        cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_EAX)
        nonce = cipher.nonce
        ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(Data)
        # Decryption:
        # Brute Force Cycle Attempt Function
        path = 'Outputfile.txt'
        list = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()/?":;.>,<{][}+=-_`|\~'
        trys = 10000000
        length = 32
        new = open(path, 'w')
        print(new)
         for i in range (0 , trys)   :
           seg1 = "b'"
           seg2 = "'"
           #Remember to add random.choice() to A in order to set the correct amount of random
           #variable searches based on your grep search
           #New instances must be based on the length of the password searched for
           A = random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list) ,random.choice(list),random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list),random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list), random.choice(list)
        B = "".join(A)
        key = A[:0] + seg1
        key = A[:33] + seg2
        # ^ Joining all segments -- DEPENDS ON LENGTH for 256 = 32 random.choice()
        f = open("Outputfile.txt", "a")
        print("Try:",i, "Out of:", trys, B, file=f)
        # ^ Printing the output & writing to Outputfile

        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce=nonce)
        plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)

        try:
          cipher.verify(tag)
          print("The message is authentic", plaintext)

        except ValueError:
          print("Key incorrect or message corrupted")
          f.close()
          i += 1
```

Comment: I suspect you're using an outdated version of the `Crypto` module - possibly the original PyCrypto, rather than its replacement PyCryptodome.

Comment: That was exactly correct! Thank you!